# How to format correctly with log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using log4j now essentially to output to a .log file. I understand it has more capabilities beyond this but the code I'm working with already uses a logger in several of its classes.

Anyway, all I have written (for now) in this class when I want to log stuff is:

```
_logger.info("<pre>\n" + toString() + "/n</pre>";
```

For some reason the output looks like complete garbage even though the toString was already painstakingly designed so this'd be formatted nicely.

"DEBUG - Here is some DEBUG

INFO - Here is some INFO

WARN - Here is some WARN

ERROR - Here is some ERROR

FATAL - Here is some FATAL"

Additionally, the above is also randomly printed in two places of the output and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you let us have a look at your configuration? At least the relevant parts... Also, what kind of _garbage_?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up finding the problem and it was completely unrelated to log4j--I am a fool

The actual problem was that I was opening the output file with notepad, which ignores "\n"

I replaced all the instances of "\n" with System.getProperty("line.separator") and now it works fine